# How to get the value of one column based on another column value

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a data set containing 4 columns. I would like to get last entry of `time` column per `col1` and `col3`, for `col1 = 1` the last entry is `2018-05-01 23:34:00`  and for `col1 = 2` the last entry is `2018-05-01 05:48:00` see if the difference between last entry and second to last entry (for example for `col1 = 1` is `2018-04-30 01:58:00`) is greater than 24 hours or not. That's also the interest for `col2=2`.

If so, I want to get the value in `col2` corresponding to last and second to last entry and change the value in `col2`, corresponding to the second to last entry of time, to `null`.

Here is part of data:

```
       time           col1     col2     col3
 2018-04-29 02:12:00    1       50        3
 2018-04-30 01:58:00    1       40        3
 2018-05-01 23:34:00    1       11        3
 2018-04-29 02:02:00    2       10        4
 2018-05-01 05:48:00    2       25        4
```

The output that I would like to have is:

```
 col1     col2         col3
  1       [11, Null]     3
  2       [25, Null]     4
```

How can I filter out the value in col2, and make it like the above given the 4 columns that I have initially?

Comment: Would appreciate  if you show us what you have tried to achieve this so far? tried code so far.

Answer (score 1):

This may help ..

```
>>> df
                  time  col1  col2  col3
0  2018-04-29 02:12:00     1    50     3
1  2018-04-30 01:58:00     1    40     3
2  2018-05-01 23:34:00     1    11     3
3  2018-05-01 05:48:00     2    10     4
4  2018-04-29 02:02:00     2    25     4
```

We can get the last occurrence of each `col1` grouping as below..

```
>>> df.groupby(['col1'], as_index=False).last()
   col1                time  col2  col3
0     1 2018-05-01 23:34:00    11     3
1     2 2018-05-01 05:48:00    25     4
```

Now we can store that into a variable as `last_diff` for later comparison.

```
>>> last_diff = df.groupby(['col1'], as_index=False).last()
```

Now we can calculate the time difference using `pd.DateOffset` looking for more then 24 hours to get the boolean exp based on comparison it will return `True` or `False` ..

```
>>> last_diff['time_diff'] = (last_diff['time'] + pd.DateOffset(days=0)).dt.hour > 24

>>> last_diff
   col1                time  col2  col3  time_diff
0     1 2018-05-01 23:34:00    11     3      False
1     2 2018-05-01 05:48:00    25     4      False
```

Comment: Well this is not the output I am looking for. And, your df is not as like as mine!! your value of row 3 in column "time", is same as value of row 4 in column "time"!

Comment: What  you are looking for not a good in pandas DF as you are trying to create a list in `col2` by calculating the time diff  and then tying them in !

Comment: Well this solution is not solving my problem, but the point is why `time_diff` is having False. It shouldn't have False if there are compared with the "second to last" value since the interval between them is more than 24!